# How do I make a variable able to be used for the entire sheet but not for different sheets?

Tags: python, class, variables

I have a class and I define variables when I call the class. But if I define them in one place they aren't defined in the other. I tried using globals but then I when I call the class it says they are already defined.

How do i define it only in one function and have that definition work for the others?

Here is my code:

Sheet 1:

```
class Addresses():        



       def __init__(self, address, variableName):

             if header == address:
                   <do something>
             if header == variableName:
                   <do something>


       def calculateAddress(self):
               if header == address:
                    <calculate address>
               if header == variableName:
                    <store it>
```

Sheet 2:

```
registers = Addresses(address = 'Base Address', variableName = 'Variable Name')

registers.calculateAddress()
```

**This is the error I get:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sheet 2", line 227, in <module>
   registers.calculateAddress()
  File "sheet 1", line 286, in calculateAddress
    if header == address:
NameError: global name 'address' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use instance variables assigned to the instance. And later call them like this,

```
class Addresses():        

   def __init__(self, address, variableName):

         self.adress = adress
         self.variableName = variableName

         if header == address: # you can use address of self.address here
               <do something>  # One may prefer self.address for continuity in the code
         if header == variableName: 
               <do something>

   def calculateAddress(self):

           if header == self.address:
                <calculate address>
           if header == self.variableName:
                <store it>
```

It is the same as defining variables in functions without any classes. You have to consider the scope of that function while defining. Which OOP presents this nice way of overcoming this.